# Plot candles ONLY if the rsi is overbought/oversold

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to plot red candles only if the rsi is overbought/oversold, seems like everything i do i get an error message.  This is what i have, and have tried so far

```
///RSI///

Length = input(title="rsi_L", type=input.integer, defval=14)'
Overbought = input(title="OB",defval=80)
Oversold = input(title="OS", defval=20)

rsi = rsi(close, Length)

plot(rsi, title="rsi", linewidth=1, color=color.orange, transp=0)
hline(Overbought, title="OB", linewidth=1, color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(Oversold, title="OS", linewidth=1, color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid)


///Downbar///

downbar = close < open


///What I've Tried///

test1 = downbar and Overbought ? color.red : color.black
bgcolor(test1, transp=0)

test2 = if downbar >= Overbought ? color.red : color.black
bgcolor(test2, transp=0)

test3 = if downbar and Overbought ? color.red : color.black
bgcolor(test3, transp=0)
```

I'm sure its an obvious fix, but i have no idea how to do it.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 8, you have an apostrophe at the end of the line, this will return an error.

You don't need `if` in `test2` or `test3`, you did it correctly with `test1`.

You can't use comparison operators when using a boolean (`downbar` in your script), also `Overbought` is not a boolean but an input.

Finally, `bgcolor` will color the chart background, not the candles, you want to use `barcolor` instead.

This script should do what you want.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
///RSI///

Length = input(title="rsi_L", type=input.integer, defval=14)
Overbought = input(title="OB",defval=80)
Oversold = input(title="OS", defval=20)

rsi = rsi(close, Length)

plot(rsi, title="rsi", linewidth=1, color=color.orange, transp=0)
hline(Overbought, title="OB", linewidth=1, color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(Oversold, title="OS", linewidth=1, color=color.white, linestyle=hline.style_solid)

barcolor(close < open and rsi > Overbought ? #ff1100 : na)
```